# MS CRM: messagepropertyname attribute in sdkmessageprocessingstepimage entity

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I'm working on a project to automate plugin registration, so that instead of having to register/update a plugin on every add/update of a dll, we can address the executable I'm making in an after-build event of the plugin dll.

So far, I managed to register assemblies, plugins and plugin steps. However, when I want to register an image on a step, I get an exception and I'm informed that I have to provide a value for the property `messagepropertyname` in the entity `sdkmessageprocessingstepimage`, which I'm trying to create.

After some googling and debugging, I learned that this value can be either `"Target"`, `"Id"` or `"EntityMoniker"`. I've also learned that it depends on the message of the step which one it is. On a Create, there's no target, so the value will be `"Id"`.

I was wondering:

- Is there a list of messages with their respective messagepropertynames?
- Or even better: is there a way to get this attribute value from somewhere else, for example from the `sdkmessagefilter` entity, which holds the connection between the entityname and the message you want to use?

Comment: If you look at the source code for https://pluginregcrm2011.codeplex.com/ you'll find almost everything you need. It's different from what you describe, as it works off an XML config file, but it has all the code for registering DLLs and steps.

Comment: You can create an image for each message and check the resulting `messagepropertyname` value. For CRUD operations it should generally be `Target`.